# monotouch problem with PresentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a problem I cannot figure out how to solve.
Basically I'm trying to show a map as modal view using the PresentModalViewController of a UITableViewController.

The table view controller has a custom cell that contains 2 buttons. One of them is "show on map" button. The application has a tab bar and a navigation bar. 
When I call PresentModalViewController the map is actually showed (I mean without errors) correctly but my problem is that the top part of the map view goes under the navigation bar and not on top.

the snippet I'm using is this one:

```
cellController.ItemButton.TouchUpInside += delegate
{
  var map = new MapViewController(item);
  this._tableViewController.PresentModalViewController(map, true);
};
```

where "this" is type of UITableViewController

Any idea of this behaviour?

Comment: are you sure the order of the controllers is correct? You have a UITabBarController, with one of the tab controllers being the navigation bar, and then your controller inside it? You should be able to just do this.PresentModalViewController() from your controller if everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calling PresentModalViewController on your NavigationController and not on the TableViewController.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I already tried using this._tableViewController.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(_mail, true); but for some reason NavigationController is null